# The CORRECT way to redirect to a ListView from StandardSetController?

Tags: apex, list-view, pagereference, redirect, standardsetcontroller

From a List Button or Visualforce Page, I wanna redirect to a ListView after. Common, right?

Life is great when we're dealing with Standard Controller: using `view()` method.

**What is the correct, documented, future-proof way to do this from a Standard Set Controller?**

```
public PageReference back() {

    //this seems so fragile and lightning-unfriendly: "/001?fcf=00B24000004cfLK"

    SelectOption listViewOption = controller.getListViewOptions()[0];

    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/' + SObjectType.Account.KeyPrefix);

    pr.getParameters().put('fcf', listViewOption.getValue().left(15));

    return pr;

}
```

---

I had some some ideas using ApexPages.Action but they caused kooky Internal Salesforce Errors:

```
public PageReference back() {

    String expression = '{!URLFOR($Action.My__c.List, $ObjectType.My__c)}';

    ApexPages.Action action = new ApexPages.Action(expression);

    return action.invoke();

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whoa. This works:

```
public PageReference listView() {

    return new ApexPages.Action('{!List}').invoke();
    //System.PageReference[/a09?fcf=00B24000004cfLK]

}
```

But is it documented?

Comment: Not explicitly with `{!list}` but it is here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_pages_action.htm - it shows `{!save}` **AND** https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_actions.htm -  shows `list` so you have to infer the items together to get to where you got

Comment: Wait a second, did I mistake _Standard Set Controller_ for _List Controller_ all these years? @Eric

Comment: nope, I did not even catch that.....But i believe they share the same prototype object or something...no expert at all here but it would appear based on what you found that there is something shared between them

Comment: `StandardSetController objects allow you to create list controllers similar to` - So a set controller lets you create a list controller(s) so just a set of lists lol - no wonder we get confused...Please tell me if I am completely wrong here, just trying to help, not trying to say I *know* anything

Comment: What foxed me is that it worked on set controller; where `list()` method is absent O_o @Eric

Comment: Have you attempted to compile while using a standard set controller and attempting to execute the `list()` method? Would be interesting if it compiled and validate what you are seeing. Wish I was near an org ATM

Comment: Ding ding ding... `Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [ApexPages.StandardSetController].list()` @Eric

Comment: lol - As Microsoft would say - Working as designed.....